# ASP.NET Custom validator for unique entry is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, customvalidator, custom-validators

I am trying to implement a custom validator  to comapare the values in database so that the entry is unique - in my registration page.

This is my aspx page

```
    <h4>  Sign up  </h4>

    <div class="">
        <div class="status">
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
                ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister" HeaderText="Sorry we could not process request because:"
                CssClass="error" />
        </div>

        <p class="input-block last">
            <label for="<%=uxEmployerName.ClientId %>">
                <strong>Company Name</strong> (required)
            </label>

            <asp:TextBox ID="uxEmployerName" runat="server" CssClass="uxemail" TabIndex="10"
                ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxEmployerNameValReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxEmployerName"
                ErrorMessage="You must enter Company Name." EnableClientScript="true"  Display="Dynamic"
                ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister" />
        </p>


        <p class="input-block last">
            <label for="<%=uxEmail.ClientId %>"> <strong>Your Email</strong> (required) </label>

            <asp:TextBox ID="uxEmail" runat="server" CssClass="uxemail" TabIndex="16" ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister" />

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxEmailValReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxEmail"
                ErrorMessage="You must enter Email." EnableClientScript="true" Display="none"
                ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister" />

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="The 'Email Address' you have entered does not appear to be a valid address."
                ControlToValidate="uxEmail" EnableViewState="False" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister" Display="None" />

            <asp:CustomValidator ID="uxEmailValUnique" runat="server" OnServerValidate="uxEmailValUnique_ServerValidate"  ErrorMessage="It appears that you already have an account with us."
                ControlToValidate="uxEmail" EnableViewState="False" ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister"
                Display="None" />

        </p>


        <p class="input-block last">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="uxRegisterButton" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true"
                ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister" CssClass="button" TabIndex="18" />

        </p>
    </div>
```

The server side code in vb.net page is

```
Private Sub uxEmailValUnique_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles uxEmailValUnique.ServerValidate
    args.IsValid = Not LocalHelper.EmailExists(uxEmail.Text)
End Sub
```

the function in LocalHelper file is

```
Shared Function EmailExists(email As String) As Boolean
    Return DB.GetInteger("select count(id) from [user] where deleted = 0 and active = 1 and email = @email", DB.SIP("email", email)) > 0
End Function
```

but the custom validator is not working. its taking duplicate email address and not giving any error message. My database is connected properly.

what is wrong in this code/ how to fix this.

Comment: your html is not showing this method `uxEmailValUnique_ServerValidate`

Comment: sorry can you elaborate. i folowed this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5z00s5e.aspx

Comment: You missed point 2)

Answer (score 1):

Create an event handler for the `CustomValidator`, that is missing in your html, control's `ServerValidate event` like this:-

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
           ControlToValidate="Text1"
           Display="Static"
           ErrorMessage="Not an even number!"
           ForeColor="green"
           Font-Names="verdana" 
           Font-Size="10pt"
           OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
           runat="server"/>
```

If this doesn't work then on `submit event` try this:-

```
Page.Validate()                
If Page.IsValid Then
   'your code 
End If
```

Your Custom Validator ServerValidate code

```
Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
    args.IsValid = False
End Sub
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its still does not work. i have edited the code like this  :   <asp:CustomValidator ID="uxEmailValUnique" runat="server" OnServerValidate="uxEmailValUnique_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="message"
                    ControlToValidate="uxEmail" EnableViewState="False" ValidationGroup="EmployerRegister"
                    Display="Static" />